# ASP.NET iFrame Session Variables

Tags: .net, session, variables, iframe

I have a login page for the admin side of a website embedded via an iFrame into the front end site.  On a button click in the embedded frame the log-in details are checked and a session variable is set.

Let's say the domain for the front end site is `http://SiteA`, the iFrame is embedded as:

```
<iframe name="myFrame" src="http://SiteB/MyLogin.aspx" ></iframe>
```

after the button click in the iFrame, the entire window on SiteA is redirected via a javascript call:

```
window.parent.location = "http://SiteB/home.aspx"
```

I want the session variable created from the iFrame, with a src of `http://SiteB`, to be stored and accessible when I'm now at SiteB after the redirect.

Is this variable still classed as a 3rd party session variable even though it was created within a frame with the same source as it is subsequently being accessed?  And if so is there an alternative way, without the use of p3p policies or resorting to the querystring?

**Additional Info**

The login.aspx pages works as desired when accessed directly, not in the iFrame.
It also works when the redirect remains within the iFrame, i.e.

```
window.location = "http://SiteB/home.aspx"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the session variable was created on the same domain, there should be no issue in accessing it from `http://SiteB/Home.aspx`.

Comment: That's what I'd thought which was why it was implemented as such.  Unfortunately it can't be accessed after the redirect to SiteB.

Comment: Can you add some code on how you're creating the session variable within the page in the iframe?

Comment: Just a straight-forward: Session["xxx"] = "xxx";  The login.aspx works as it should when not accessed within the iFrame.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? If not, which browsers are affected?